# Limiting SQL Statement to top 5 amounts

Tags: sql

How do I write a simple SELECT statment which limits the report to only the top 5 of a column value?

Answer (score 4):

You'd have to sort by that column value, maybe in descending order, depending on what you mean by "*top 5*" ; and fetching only the 5 top lines.

Using MySQL, you'd have something like this, I'd say :

```
select *
from your_table
where ...
order by your_column desc
limit 5
```

Using MSSQL server, you don't have `limit`, but you could use `top` :

```
select top 5 *
from your_table
where ...
order by your_column desc
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's not forget the SQL Server WITH TIES. If the top 6 values are the same, then the top 5 will be chosen randomly from the 6

```
SELECT TOP 5 WITH TIES... ORDER BY col DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

### Sybase

Return the first n rows.

```
select top n * from table order by column
```

This does not work because top is a keyword not a function:

```
select top(n) * from table order by column
```

Apply a limit to multiple queries using `set rowcount`

```
set rowcount n
select * from table order by column
...
set rowcount 0
```

### MySQL

[MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html)

Return the first n rows starting with row m.

```
select * from table limit m, n order by column
```

### SQL Server

Return the first n rows

```
select top n from table order by column
```

### Oracle

Return the first n rows

```
select * 
  from table 
 where rownum < 5 
 order by column
```

### SQLite

[SQLite docs](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html)

Return the first n rows

```
select * from table order by column limit(n)
```

Return the first n rows starting with row m

```
select * from table order by column limit(m,n)
```

Return the first n rows

```
select * from table order by column limit(n) offset(m)
```

### Postgres

[Postgres docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/queries-limit.html)

Return the first n rows

```
select * from table order by column limit(n)
```

Return the first n rows starting with row m

```
select * from table order by column limit(n) offset(m)
```

---

If I missed any databases or row limiting methods please post a comment and I'll add it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

oracle

select * from table where rownum < 5;

Answer (score 0):

......

**MySQL**

```
 select * from table order by field_name limit 0, 4
```

**MSSQL**

```
 select top 5 from table order by field_name
```

Comment: Are you sure the MySQL query is right?  Doesn't the 'order by' clause must come before the limit clause?  I don't have a MySQL db to test it on.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 5 LastName
FROM Employees
ORDER BY LastName
```

You have to use the order-by if you want to get them in order.  If you need them in descending order (high to low) add DESC to the end of the query.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like (in MSSQL)?:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5 column_name FROM table_name ORDER BY column_name
```

This would select only the column you were interested in, and it would make sure it wouldn't duplicate the values. If you'd like the top 5, irregardless of whether they are the same or not, you should try it without the distinct.

```
SELECT TOP 5 column_name FROM table_name ORDER BY column_name
```